# C# WPF shape rotation jagged edges

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, blurry

I am developing a software using WPF, when I draw a simple shape and rotate it for around 45', I get jagged edges. Antialiasing is not a solution, because I get blurry edges and on diagonals it simply does not work like I want. UseLayoutRounding and SnapsToDevicePixels does not help, because I think, it has something to do with line drawing algorithm. I tried the same with WinForms and I get better results, but I want to stick to WPF, because I am using some features of it already.

Code looks something like that:

1. Create a shape -> Shape = new Polygon();
2. Add shape to canvas -> DrawingLayer.Children.Add(Shape);
3. Rotate the shape -> RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(Angle, Centroid.X, Centroid.Y);
4. Update shape -> Shape.RenderTransform = rt;

WPF rotation: 
[image: WPF rotation]

WinForms rotation: 
[image: WinForms rotation]

WPF rotation with Antialiasing: 
[image: WPF rotation with Antialiasing]

Comment: How are you drawing this shape? Is it a rectangle or a path or what?

Comment: It is a polygon.

Comment: Please add sufficient markup to your question that someone can cut and paste to reproduce your issue. The easier you make it for people to help, the more likely you get a good answer.

Comment: Just added simple steps. You can test it with simple rectangle or line, I get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to comment without seeing your actual code/markup, but with this markup...

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.Question54926730"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="StackOverflow 54926730" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Canvas Height="400" Width="400">
        <Polygon Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Polygon.Points>
                <Point X="0"   Y="0" />
                <Point X="200" Y="0" />
                <Point X="200" Y="200" />
                <Point X="0"   Y="200" />
            </Polygon.Points>
            <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="100" CenterY="100" />
            </Polygon.RenderTransform>
        </Polygon>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

...the result looks good to me...

[image: WPF RotationTransform rotating a Polygon square by 45 degrees]

I notice you say you are rotating by "around" 45 degrees and, again, without seeing any code it's not clear what that means (44.95 degrees?  40 degrees?) but at both of those two angles the result looks good.  Here's the not-so-round angle of 41.3579 degrees:

[image: WPF RotationTransform rotating a Polygon square by 41.3579 degrees]

Only at multiples of 90 degrees ± 10 do I start to see a pronounced staircase effect.  Here's 9 degrees:

[image: WPF RotationTransform rotating a Polygon square by 5 degrees]

Relevant version numbers:

- 64-bit Windows 10 Pro 1809 v17763.437
- Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.0.1
- .NET Framework v4.7.2
- `PresentationCore.dll` v4.7.3362.0
- `PresentationFramework.dll` v4.7.3362.0

Comment: I have same result, when Antialiasing is turned on. It looks like it has something to do with GDI+ and WinForms, WPF is just different.